# Lookup table maintenance in Siebel?

Tags: sql, siebel

I need some high level advice.

I need a translation table for data I'm sending to a Siebel application. Can Siebel manipulate and share a simple SQL table? Is that what a Sieble expert would call a "data table"?

Answer (score 1):

All siebel updates are via the business layer ie Business Components. If you want to put up a new siebel table, create one, and create a BC on top of that.  And now, escript of workflows can be used as any other.

For simple lookups, the easiest way used in the wild is to just set it up as LOVs. This makes it easier to deploy large data changes across environments.